# NoSQL database in python: What are some of the things that "shelve" can't do?

Tags: python, mongodb, shelve, nosql

The Python Standard Library has a NoSQL database, [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html), that seems quite adequate. Yet other NoSQL (mongoDB) databases remain very popular.

If I choose shelve over the more popular alternatives, what are the main features that I will be forgoing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shelve` is just a very simple key-value store where each assignment is also written to a DB. It's interface is basically idential to that of a python `dict`, and that's it. It has no support for concurrent read/write access; multiple readers can access safely access a `shelve` DB, but if any of them could be writing, it's not safe. It's performance is not particularly good, since it's uses `pickle` to serialize the objects it stores, which isn't very fast.

Fully featured NoSQL DBs like MongoDB offers *many* more features, like replication, auto-sharding, support for indexes, more advanced querying, atomic writes, etc. Performance and scalability are going to be better, too.

That said, if you're just trying to access your DB from a single application, don't need to store very much data, don't need any kind of advanced querying, and don't need the best possible performance, then you'll probably be ok with `shelve`. Otherwise, you probably want something more robust.